# Mule - Error calling Java class

Tags: java, mule

I am getting error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class”
```

When I place any Java component like below

```
<cxf:jaxws-service>
<component class="packageName.util.Test" doc:name="Java"/>
<component doc:name="ServiceName" doc:description="Retrieves details from database">
  <spring-object bean="beanService" />
</component>
```

I get error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class`

Below is sample Java class code

```
public class Test implements Callable {

  @Override
  public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();
  }
```

**Java component calls works perfect outside jaxws tag. I need request object hence can not before jaxws tag**

I was able to call Java class and add object in session and was able to retrive same object after service call. But some how it is not working. I have tried multiple things like adding remove variable tag and every thing I know. But not sure why I am getting this error. Please help. Please let me know if you need any additional information. I am new to Mule so please advice if i am missing any basics here.
I

Answer (score 0):

There's a few broken things in your configuration:

- the `jaxws-service` element is not closed,
- it lacks a `serviceClass` attribute pointing to your service interface,
- it has two components while only one should be present, ie the actual implementation of your service.

Reference: http://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Building+Web+Services+with+CXF

Comment: <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="packageName.IUserWebProfileInfo"
doc:name="CXF service" validationEnabled="true">
<cxf:inInterceptors> <spring:bean class="packageName.SpringBeanName" /> </cxf:inInterceptors>
</cxf:jaxws-service> <component class="package.Test" doc:name="Java"/>  
<component doc:name="NameService" doc:description="Retrieves  dB><spring-object bean="ExampleService" />
</component> - This is full code. I have not mentioned full package name and actual class name since this is client code.

Comment: If this is client code, you need to use `cxf:jaxws-client`. See: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF

Comment: I am sorry for all the confusion I have been causing. When i meant client i am talking about client I am working for . CXF service is working perfectly fine without adding java component in between. Strangely Java compoenent call was working fine but all of sudden it started giving me this error.

Comment: Ah, no worries :) The fact you have two components after `cxf:jaxws-service` doesn't make sense, as I explained in my answer. There should be only one.

Comment: This is existing code where I am trying to implement Audit logging. I will look into your suggestion and try and see if I can change existing code. I will get back to you once i am done. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of calling Java component between service call I moved it after service call and stored Request object as flow Variable for later use. I can not change existing code hence this was workaround. Thanks for your input.